# iPhone 4 SDK "Ad Hoc" install error

Tags: iphone

I recently upgraded my iPhone SDK to 4.  But now when I create an "Ad Hoc" build for my customer and send him the zipped app and "ad hoc" mobile provisioning file he gets the following dialogue when attempting to install the app using iTunes 9.

"A provisioning profile named 'embedded.mobileprovision" already exists on this computer.  Do you want to replace it?"

I've been able to reproduce this with my own system so it is not a local configuration issue.

The interesting thing is my "ad hoc" builds worked fine before the upgrade and this dialogue is not occurring when I drag my provisioning file to iTunes, but occurs when the app is dragged into iTunes.

Also, when we click "replace" nothing happens. The app is not installed into iTunes and we do not see the app in the apps folder or on the devices when we sync.

I have my project set to build using iPhone 4 as the Base SDK and the deployment target is 3.0 (I've also tried 3.1.3).

I do not have any problems installing this app using my development profile.

I've been programming iPhone apps for over a year now and thought I had a handle on this crazy provisioning profile crap, but now this new SDK is giving me new problems to waste my time on.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try renaming the profile, or deleting the old embedded.mobileprovision (it should be named by GUID once installed). Or just use [iPhone Configuration Utility](http://www.apple.com/support/iphone/enterprise/), which is much less of a pain than iTunes.

Comment: I got it to work by selecting the "Application requires iPhone environment" option in my <application name>-info.plist file

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by selecting the "Application requires iPhone environment" option in my -info.plist file.